# Rally App SDK 2.0: Hide/Remove card owner and image

Tags: extjs, rally

I am having trouble with hiding/removing the card owner and image from the card headers in App SDK 2.0. This was very simple in 1.30, using just CSS, but similar CSS does not seem to work, nor does trying to programmatically remove the HTML elements from the rendering templates.

CSS:

```
.cardOwner .cardOwnerName {
    display: none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
header.renderTpl.html = '{template-card owner/image els}';
header.renderTpl.master.body = '{template-card owner/image els}';
header.renderTpl.tpls[0].body = '{template-card owner/image els}';

header.initialConfig.renderTpl.html = '{template-card owner/image els}';
header.initialConfig.renderTpl.master.body = '{template-card owner/image els}';
header.initialConfig.renderTpl.tpls[0].body = '{template-card owner/image els}';
```

I don't quite understand how the elements are still being rendered when they are removed from the templates. I don't know of any other location where the elements are specified.

The CSS does not show up in developer tools at all, which is very peculiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing it with CSS should work fine.  There are two separate classes, .cardOwner and .cardOwnerName, that need display set to none.

```
.cardOwner, 
.cardOwnerName {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Ah... Silly me.. I forgot the comma. I suppose that was my downfall. It works now. I can't believe I didn't notice that while going through it.   Late nights and early mornings..